# Create production configuration with additional compile dependency in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to define build script for my production versions.

Below is project structure, all projects are `java` plugin.

```
wrapper (parent)
|--frontend (child)
|  |--src
|  |  |--js (raw ES6 modules)
|  |  |--sass (raw)
|  |--build
|     |--lib
|     |  |--production-front.jar
|     |--dist
|        |--js (bundled)
|        |--css (compiled production)
|--backend (child) (spring boot)
   |--build
      |--lib
         |--RELEASE.jar
```

Now what happens here is that by default (`sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs`) of `backend` is linked directly to:

- **raw** `:frontent/src/js`
- **generated** `:frontent/build/dist/css`.

This way when you run it, by default it will be in dev mode. Here it means that it will:

- use **generated** scss->css files (which are resource so for example if you run background gulp-sass that compiles it every time you change scss, css will update and boom, fast dev cycle).
- use **raw** JS which is compiled directly in browser (JSPM, SystemJS, Babel) - so you only need to edit `:frontent/src/js` and refresh page.

Okay, so while dev is love, I also need to compile for production. Project structure mentioned above also shows where `:frontend` generates `production-front.jar`.

Here is default java build tree with my notes.

[image]

**EDIT**
I need to make dependency that will compile `production-front.jar` into `RELEASE.jar` and ommit mentioned attached resources.

Note that I need to only ommit those resources, not any others in `main.resources.srcDirs`.

What is **proper way** to solve this (one that is not making tasks that e.g remove dev resources from .jar and then throw in other production-front.jar instead)? I cannot grasp how would i make multiple sourceSets or configurations that work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very in-depth Gradle learning for over past week (this topic was created because I was close to my demise) I've finally found very satisfying solution.

I'd like to share what were my goals and final solution:

- Have smallest possible build.gradle
- Have possibility to develop with `build --continuous`
- Make it so that `eclipse` plugin (probably also other IDEs) can **perfectly** mirror pure command line Gradle development with their own build system.

This is a multi-project with one of them being Spring Boot application with DevTools.

```
wrapper (parent)
|--frontend (child)
|  |--src-client
|  |  |--static
|  |  |  |--img (images)
|  |  |  \--js (raw ES6 modules)
|  |  \--sass (raw, note not in static folder)
|  \--build
|     |--lib
|     |  \--front.jar
|     |--dist
|     |  |--js (bundled, minimized)
|     |  \--css (compiled production, minimized)
|     \--dev
|        \--css (compiled dev, compact readable format)
\--backend (child) (spring boot)
   |--src
   |  |--main/java
   |  |--main/resources
   |  \--test/java
   \--build
      \--lib
         \--application.jar
```

As I described, goals were to:

- Have `bootRun` run with **raw** sources for js and **compiled** css, but also with every resource that is included in `backend`'s `main`.
- Have `bootJar` compile into production with dependency on compiled `front.jar` instead of everything that is used in dev (previous point).

I've used combination of configurations, sourceSets and bootRun properties (+ a lot of time).

Here are files (stripped down):

**wrapper/build.gradle**

```
wrapper.gradleVersion '5.0-milestone-1'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}
```

**wrapper/front/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java' // possibly use java-base or just custom zip task, since client doesn't actually compile java
}

jar {
    dependsOn buildProduction // task that compiles my stuff into build/dist
    baseName 'front'
    classifier 'SNAPSHOT-' + new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
    from(buildDir.absolutePath + '/dist') {
        into 'static'
    }
}

// Note there is a lot of other tasks here that actually compile my stuff, like gulp-sass and JSPM bundling with babel transpiler.
```

**wrapper/backend/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.RC1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 10 // eclipse has (or had) problems with Java 11
targetCompatibility = 10

sourceSets {
    // 'java' plugin adds default main sourceSet
    dev {
        resources.srcDirs = [
            project(':front').projectDir.absolutePath + '/src-client',
            project(':front').buildDir.absolutePath + '/dev'
        ]
    }
}

bootJar {
    baseName 'application'
    classifier 'SNAPSHOT-' + new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS')
    // I used bootArchives since it was already there and my stuff fits description, you can also define your own configuration and extend runtime one.
    classpath configurations.bootArchives
}

bootRun {
    sourceResources sourceSets.dev // I make bootRun (dev) use dev sourceSet
}

dependencies {
    runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    // Since bootArchives configuration is used only by bootJar (not bootRun), this will be only in final fat .jar
    bootArchives project(':front')
    ...
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
```

Some link that helped:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradle-goodness-adding-dependencies.html

Note that client's source folder is called `src-client`: This is key for making "**perfect** mirror" in eclipse. If we would name it `src` which is already being used by `main` in `backend` eclipse would vomit with name clash (which probably can be fixed by configurating eclipse plugin, but then again - we wanted to keep it simple, without IDE configurations).

As final result we get very nice command line development with gradle's continuous building and also EXACTLY mirrored behaviour in eclipse which defaults its configuration to work in the same way (but use eclipse's builder instead of gradle's). We also get nice linked folders in `backend` project to sources used from `front`. Same would probably apply to IDEA :).